# Prove of Quadratic residual

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Let $p$ be a prime and $q$ a primitive root modulo $p$. How do I show that q is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $a \equiv q^{2k}\pmod p$ for some integer $k$?

Comment: You say show that $a$ is a quadratic residue if and only if..., what is $a$?  Did you mean $q$?

Comment: @jim yes, sorry there was an error

Comment: @benji_r, it should be $a\equiv q^{2k}\pmod p$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee yes you are write and thank you for the answer it was perfect , do you have any idea about this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335884/i-wanna-prove-if-the-composite-are-equal-to-each-other

Comment: The statement makes no sense... $p\equiv q^2  \bmod p$? Well, $p\equiv 0 \bmod p$, so $0\equiv p\equiv q^{2k}\bmod p$ makes no sense if $q$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo This is a homework question from a book

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, did you down-vote the Question and/or the Answer?

Comment: I only downvoted the question because the statement was wrong, and it is still wrong. Do you mean "*How do I show that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ ...*"? Obviously, if $q$ is a primitive root, then $q$ is not a quadratic residue.

Comment: Please refine the statement of the question further. As far as I am concerned, this is still wrong. It should be as stated by Alvaro Lozano-Robledo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $q$ is a is a quadratic residue modulo $p,$ there exists an integer $b$ such that $a\equiv b^2\pmod p$

Now, as $q$ is a primitive root $\pmod p,$ for each distinct integer $k\in[1,p-1],$ we shall have one of the $p-1$ in-congruent integers $b \pmod p$

So, $a\equiv b^2\equiv q^{2k}\pmod p$

Conversely, if $a\equiv q^{2k}\pmod p$ for some integer $k\in[1,p-1]$ and $q$ is a primitive root $\pmod p,$ there exists some integer $b\equiv q^k\pmod p\implies a\equiv q^{2k}\pmod p\equiv(b)^2$

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I got it :))

Comment: @benji_r, my pleasure. Would you rectify the Question please?

Comment: what do you mean by rectify?

Comment: @benji_r,  if and only if $a≡q^{2k}(\pmod p) $ in the question

Comment: I just fixed it. Do you have any idea on this one   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335884/i-wanna-prove-if-the-composite-are-equal-to-each-other

Comment: How come your answer got down vote?

Comment: @benji_r, wish I knew and wish they was enforcement of reasoning before down-voting!

Comment: Maybe is my prof lol Not happy to see this